# Index for Order By in n1ql

Tags: indexing, query-optimization, couchbase, sql++

Hope everyone is doing well.

I was trying to optimize a N1Ql query with order by clause by creating index.I got a doubt does order of orderby columns and where column should be kept same to have a proper index or ordering doesn't matter in couchbase 6.0.3.
Below is query

```
Select * from employee where type= employee and number='123' and division='456'
order by class,number
```

Index could be

```
Create index idx_123 on employee(number,division,class) where type='employee'
```

But performance is not great using index.Any suggestion here.

Comment: Can you include the exact columns you intend to select?  Or, do you really want to select all columns in the table?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen So use case is to include all columns and hence fetch is happening

Answer (score 2):

The following query and index uses index order. You can verify by doing EXPLAIN and check (no "#operator": "Order" at the end)

```
CREATE INDEX idx_where ON employee (division, class, `number`) WHERE type ="employee";

SELECT * 
FROM employee
WHERE type= "employee" 
     AND `number`='123' 
     AND division='456'
ORDER BY class, `number`;
```

As projection contains *, it must fetch the documents that might be taking time.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your current index is that it does not cover the where, order by, or select portions of your query.  For a possible immediate improvement, try adding the following index which covers the where clause:

```
CREATE INDEX idx_where ON employee (type, number, division);
```

We could also try improving on the above to cover the `ORDER BY` clause, but if you would always be expecting modestly-sized result sets (say < 100 records), then a manual hash sort might not be a big performance problem.  Note that covering the select clause is probably out of the question given that you are doing a `SELECT *`.

Comment: why you suggested to go  index creation on whole type rather than going for partial index on type

Comment: I am not familiar with partial indices, but in any case Couch DB might not even use your current index because it omits the `type` column.

Comment: FYI Couch DB does not support N1QL - this is Couchbase (common mistake)

Answer (score 0):

In this case issue was with size of document was around 20 MB that is maximum document size to be indexes and hence index was unable to cover this up and performing poorly.
We removed that document and it worked.
Thanks everyone for suggestion.